# Stream Analytics and Azure EventHub

Tags: c#, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

I have a Stream Analytics job that reads from an Azure EventHub. I am trying to read a property of the message in the job. I am talking specifically about a property that is attached to the EventHub message, like the following:

var Event = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serialized));
Event.Properties.Add("tableName", tableName);

I want to read the "tableName" property in my Stream Analytics job. Is this possible from Stream Analytics or do I have to setup a EventHostProcessor to be able to read these properties?

If it is possible how do I test this in the Azure Management Portal? I don't have an easy way of seeing what the EventData object looks like before it is sent to the EventHub via the EventHubClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading message custom properties are not supported directly by ASA as of now. So it needs to be in the EventData payload to be consumed. However there is effort planned in near future to enable this, so please look out for future announcements in this regard. cheers !

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I thought might be the case. I'll stay tuned for future announcements.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use this function to read the user properties from EventHub in your Stream Analytics query/job --

```
select GetMetadataPropertyValue(ehInput, "[User].[tableName]") as tableName from ehInput
```

cheers!

Comment: ans documentation for this, I found nothing on google :(

Comment: Here is the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/getmetadatapropertyvalue?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396